# Creating exception for substring match

Tags: php

```
if ( strpos($weight, 'g') !== false ) { ... }
elseif ( stripos($weight, 'kg') !== false ) { ... }
```

The first condition matches all `kg` weights as well. I only want to match `xxx g` or `xxg`, ie. min two digits (to exlude 2g, 3g, 4g) followed by 'g' or digits, space and `g`

Comment: Just put your elseif on top? I.e. the first condition should test for kg, the elseif should test for the g.

Comment: Regex would be far easier to use in this case.

Comment: REGX `[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[g]` will test for both cases

Comment: @Merv Thought about that, but still `g` is too common and might yield unknown results.

Comment: what about @Merv suggestion ? i think that would work too

Comment: @3zzy then your conditions are invalid. My suggestion was to test for kg first, then the regular g. If it didn`t find the kg, you can then test for the other cases, like mg or g.

Comment: add some inputs and expected output it'll clarify what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only capture xxx g or xx g or xxxg or xxg you can use regex to test your use case.

An example regex could be something like:

```
<?php

if( preg_match('/\d{2,} ?g/', $input) ){
    // this should only work for:
    // 12g, 12 g, 123g, 123 g, 1235g, 1234 g
}
```

Comment: `\d{2,} ?g` would be better. `\d` is equal to `[0-9]`. There is no need to `[\d]`. Same with `{2,}+` - `{2,}` means from 2 to unlimited. There is no need in extra `+`.

Comment: I agree. I'll modify the regex, I was gonna test for any number of digits first but later saw he wanted 2 digits or more.. Also, I removed the `()` as capturing the matches is not required